# Ajax file upload with ie9

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, internet-explorer-9

I have a jQuery script that posts a file to an ASP page using Ajax.

It works fine with Chrome, but I am experiencing problems with IE9.

Because IE9 wasn't reading the FormData() function, I added the if statement:

```
if(typeof FormData == "undefined"){
```

But now I am getting this error in the console:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined
```

Here is the full code:

```
        <INPUT type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <a id="upload_file" class="button">
            Upload File
        </a>

        <script>
        $("a#upload_file").click(function(){

            if(typeof FormData == "undefined"){
                var data = [];
                jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                      data.push('file-'+i, file);
                });
            } else {
                var data = new FormData();
                jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                      data.append('file-'+i, file);
                });
            }

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'file_save.asp',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    $("#upload_success").text("Your file has uploaded successfully.");
                    $("#file_location").val("files/" + data);
                    $(".filename").html("");
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: FormData is the only way to do ajax file upload, if it isn't available you'll have use some other method(like the iframe trick) or just not use Ajax.